# R markdown with Latex on R studio cloud server

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am trying to use Rmarkdown on our department's RStudio server. I am using the tinytex package to install TinyTex, for the Rmarkdown files. It was working before, then I was trying to get a custom latex template to work and somehow managed to mess up my latex setup. I have tried a fresh install of TinyTeX through the tinytex package which doesn't help.

I get the following errors when knitting:

```
! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt

! mktexfmt [ERROR]: -user mode but path setup is -sys type, bailing out.
```

Addtional Info :

1)

```
cat /proc/version
```

yields

Linux version 4.15.0-72-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-026) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:20:02 UTC 2019

2)
The following minimal example gives the same problem:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

## R Markdown

## Including Plots
```

5) 
Log file is not useful just contains only the above errorr message

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is (at present) a little hard to help you as there is little tangible information in your post.  Additional pointers that may help us:

1. What Linux distro (and version) does that server run?  This alone may be important---in 25 years of LaTeX on Debian/Ubuntu, I have almost always found all required fonts or styles in the distro itself (and tinytex either did not or does not work due to, IIRC, orthogonal views on whether path info is user or system based).
2. Can you, or can you not, run a minimal document?  If you try a five-line document maybe just setting document type, a section and a title, does that work?
3. Can you get hold of a different setup just for checks?  https://rstudio.cloud is a pretty decent alternative just to check the sanity of your attempt.
4. Tinytex tries a herculean task of intercepting all possible errors on all possible OSs. That is hard to impossible to get right; consequently it has fooled a very senior R developer and myself more than once pointing the wrong way.
5. Do you have a .log file produced by the command you ran?  Does it have any information?

tinytex is well-liked by a lot of people, it clearly helps in some situations. That said, in *my* use cases it mostly seems to get in the way but do not let that stop you.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the post.

Comment: Thanks, so now we know "Ubuntu" and 18.04. Good. Next, what you show is _RMarkdown_ document.  To debug (La)TeX I recommend running just `pdflatex` on a .tex file.   Finally, now that we know it is Ubuntu we can more easily test in, say, a Docker container.  It all starts with `dpkg -l 'texlive*'`.  (That said, I am now at 19.10 so three releases newer and some packages have changed...)

Comment: pdflatex on a .tex file. : this gives : ```kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
mktexfmt [ERROR]: -user mode but path setup is -sys type, bailing out.
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!``` . Same as before,  Running ``` dpkg -l 'texlive*'``` gives me a bunch of I guess TeX packages - around 8, but I don't know how this is helpful to me.

Comment: It is helpful. You essentially need to compare to a _working_ and comparable installation.  So maybe rstudio.cloud? When I run `dpkg -l | grep texlive | wc -l` there I get _18_ packages (on Ubuntu 16.04).  On my server I have 27 packages.  So 8 sounds like too few, and _if basic latexing does not work_ we should probably start there.  Can you get hold of your sysadmin(s)?